# Need faster python code for calculating sample entropy

Tags: python, numpy, entropy

This is the problem I have faced when I am writing python code for sample entropy.

`map(max, abs(a[i]-a) )` is very slow.

Is there any other function perform better than `map()` ?

Where `a` is ndarray that looks like `np.array([ [1,2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5,6],[3,4,5,3,2] ])`

Comment: What's `a` here? And is this Python 2.x or 3.x (`map()` is not the same in both)?

Comment: have you tried `import speed`? Seriously though, what does `a` look like and what is the required output?

Comment: is `a` a `numpy.ndarray`? (you can check this doing `type(a)`)...

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the vectorized max

```
>>> map(max, abs(a[2]-a) )
[3, 4, 0]
>>> np.abs(a[2] - a).max(axis=1)
array([3, 4, 0])
```